# Can I place my application code on partition in my RAM?

Tags: linux, testing, ram, solid-state-drive

I want use RAM instead of SSD. I'm looking for experienced people to give me some advice about this. I want to mount a partition and put into it my Rails app.

Any ideas?

UPD: I tested the SSD and RAM. I have a OSX with 4x4Gb Kingston @ 1333 RAM, Intel Core i3 @ 2,8 Ghz, OCZ Vertex3 @ 120Gb, HDD Seagate ST3000DM001 @ 3Tb. My OS installed on SSD and ruby with gems placed in home folder on SSD. I create new Rails app with 10.000 product items in sqlite and create controller with code:

```
@products = Product.all
Rails.cache.clear
```

Tested it with AB.

## SSD

```
Document Length:        719 bytes
Concurrency Level:      4
Time taken for tests:   39.274 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      130600 bytes
HTML transferred:       71900 bytes
Requests per second:    2546.21
Transfer rate:          3325.35 kb/s received
Connnection Times (ms)
            min     avg     max
Connect:    0       0       0
Processing: 398     1546    1627
Total:      398     1546    1627
```

## RAM

```
Document Length:        719 bytes
Concurrency Level:      4
Time taken for tests:   39.272 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      130600 bytes
HTML transferred:       71900 bytes
Requests per second:    2546.33
Transfer rate:          3325.51 kb/s received
Connnection Times (ms)
            min     avg     max
Connect:    0       0       0
Processing: 366     1546    1645
Total:      366     1546    1645
```

## HDD

```
Document Length:        719 bytes
Concurrency Level:      4
Time taken for tests:   40.510 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      130600 bytes
HTML transferred:       71900 bytes
Requests per second:    2468.54
Transfer rate:          3223.92 kb/s received
Connnection Times (ms)
            min     avg     max
Connect:    0       0       0
Processing: 1193    1596    2400
Total:      1193    1596    2400
```

So, I think that thing in ruby with gems placed on SSD and get this scripts slowly, I will test on a real server and puts all ruby scripts into RAM with more complicated code or real application.

*ps: sorry for my english :)*

Comment: look into tmpfs, its an easy way to make a ramdisk

Comment: Well you always can do a ramdisk, whether on linux or windows or whatever, but if you run your application, it will be probably in the ram by startup anyway, so what do you want to achieve? Describe your program and why you got the "idea" in the first place, otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a [ramdisk](http://www.google.com/#q=linux+ramdisk).

Comment: I now about ramdisk, but thanks, I am looking for experienced people to give me some advice about this. I want to mount a partition and put into it my Rails app.

Comment: @ArtemevYurii, if that was what you wanted to know, maybe you should have said so in your question.